# C:\Intepub\wwwroot folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7

I have created a sample web service in asp.net and I have published this to a folder.
Now, the actual problem is I could not found C:\Intepub\wwwroot where i have to copy that folder for consuming my web service in my web application.

What I have to do? I am having Windows 7 installed on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a virtual directory and put the published site in that folder without need of C:\Intepub\wwwroot, Make sure you have IIS installed as the  C:\Intepub\wwwroot is default virtual directory for IIS. This is how you can [**make virtual directory**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138).